# Can I pray missed Tahajjud prayers?

Tags: salat-qada, tahajjud

Can I make up missed Tahajjud prayers of past days? It can be of few years? Can I pray these during day time?

JazakAllah Khair

Comment: I cannot find the hadith, but I am sure that I read in riyad saliheen, that Umar (ra) said that if you for some reason were unable to pray your tahajjud in the night-time, you can make it up in the morning.  I don't know about making up for years of missed tahajjid though.

Answer (score 0):

If you miss any prayer due to sleep or forgetfulness, you can make it up as soon as you remember or can pray it.

Answer (score 0):

From my knowledge, only fardh salah can be made up in any time period and fajr sunnahs before sunrise.

As tahajjud is not obligatory and fully optional, tahajjud can not be made up from a long time.

Also, if you find it hard to wake up for tahajjud, 2 or 4 rakaats after the witr of isha will inshallah suffice for the reward of tahajjud

Answer (score -2):

You can pray Al-witr prayer after pray Al-duha prayer, but the Al-tahajud prayer needs to be prayed in its own time. But if you slept or forgot about it, there's no problem.